# How do I signup users using PFObject instead of PFUsers()

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I have created a PFObject called UserDataTable which stores information like username, password, Name, emailID, age, city, state, etc. of the user.

I am not sure how to authenticate the user to server using PFObject but can do so using PFUsers(). I know that PFUsers is a sub-class of PFObject so there must be a way to access those properties using my PFObject.

Can anyone help me out with the same. I am using SWIFT for coding.

```
let UserDataBase = PFObject(className: "UserDataBase") 
UserDataBase["userId"] = "aamirdbx"
UserDataBase["userName"] = "Aamir Bilal"
UserDataBase["userPassword"] = "pass"
UserDataBase["userEmailId"] = "aamirdbx@gmail.com"
```

I would like to Sign In using information in this UserDataBase which is a PFObject.

I know how we can do the same using PFUser() but I want to avoid using a bunch of different Objects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be using `PFUser` for this no matter what. `PFUser` already has all the built in authentication protocols, session tokens, security and ACL built in for you, which as someone who is just getting started is not something you want to try and manage yourself. You can add extra information to your Parse User class if you need to store additional information, or you can create another table, and have a pointer in your user class to the data in the other table, but for your sake and your user's sake, please don't try to handle this yourself.

Answer (score 0):

After that chunk of code you should call userDataBase.saveInBackground() or saveInBackgroundWithBlock but then you would have to do a lot more coding every time they log in to authenticate and sync objects with the user etc. The included PFUser subclass does a lot of the heavy lifting for you, plus you can add properties to the user subclass so that would probably be a better option.

Comment: Yes I am familiar with the SaveInBackgroundWithBlock() 
How then do I link the 2 tables? I'm sorry but the parse documentation is not something you can really call helpful for a amateur.